# why I am unable to populate the likes on post and it give me error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

LIKES SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const likesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },

    likeable : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required : true,
        refPath : "onModel"
    } , 
    onModel : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        enum : ["Posts" , "Comments"]
    }
} , {
    timestamps : true
})

const Likes = mongoose.model("Likes" , likesSchema);
module.exports = Likes;
```

### I don,t know how to handel these problem, when i run the server it gives me this error:"Cannot populate path `likes` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override."

```
const Post =require('../models/post');
const User=require('../models/user');
module.exports.home= async function(req,res){
  // console.log(req.cookies);
    // return res.render('home',{
    //    title:"Home"
    // })
  try{
    let posts = await Post.find({})
      .sort("-createdAt")
      .populate("user")
      .populate({
        path: "comments",
        populate: {
          path: "user",
        },
      })
      .populate({
        path: "comments",
        populate: {
          path: "likes",
        },
      })
      .populate("likes");
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.